# How to get Quote Item Id after adding a product to cart?

Tags: magento, checkout, cart, quote

I want quote item id every time a product added to cart. I have tried many event they return the quote item object but object doesn't contain quote item id as it exists only when cart save to the db. So is there any event which will return the quote item object with quote item id?

I have used following events

```
checkout_cart_product_add_after
sales_quote_add_item
```

but it will not return quote_item_id in

```
public function addItemToSalesModelInfo(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
}
```

Comment: Post the effort and code that you have tried so far, and where you are facing the problem

Answer (score 3):

You are using a correct event i.e.

```
checkout_cart_product_add_after
```

to access quote item id, you need to use,

```
$item = $observer->getQuoteItem()
```

you can access all quote item info like

`$item->getProductId()` etc..

Comment: hi , it will return the product that i have added to the cart not quote item id.

Comment: yes it will, as you have $item object which is a sales_flat_quote_item instance

Comment: print the $item object , you will get all details.

Comment: The item id is only available if the item already existed in the cart. If it is completely new the item will not have an id.

Answer (score 2):

The item id is only available `checkout_cart_product_add_after` if a fitting item already existed in cart. You will actually have to work in two steps. Listen to `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and add a flag to the item.

```
$item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
$item->setLastAdded(true);
```

And then listen to `sales_quote_item_save_after` and add the id to the session (or do whatever) if the flag is set.

```
$item = $observer->getItem();
if ($item->getLastAdded()) {
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setLastAddedItemId($item->getId());
}
```

Comment: There is a tehcnical reason to "The item id is only available checkout_cart_product_add_after if a fitting item already existed in cart"?

Answer (score 0):

Get quote and items count after adding product to cart.

```
//Save your cart
$cart->save();

//use checkout/session
$cart1=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$cart1->setCartWasUpdated(true);

// Quote ID
$result_array["quoteid"]=$quoteid=$cart1->getQuoteId();

// Items count
$result_array["items_count"]=Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
```

Answer (score -1):

To get quote id and quote's item id, you can get using below code.

```
$currentcart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$quote = $currentcart->getQuote();
$quoteItemId = $quote->getEntityId();
```

To get quote's item id

```
$quoteItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($quoteItems as $item) {
$ItemId = $item->getId();
}
```