# get quote item id after adding product to cart

Tags: php, magento

I need to get quote item id of the product when it is added to cart because I need to update a field of Db after this event,I have taken reference from [How to get Quote Item Id after adding a product to cart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113640/how-to-get-quote-item-id-after-adding-a-product-to-cart), but this is not working,I have used event: sales_quote_product_add_after and my oberver function is:

```
$quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
$id = $quoteItem->getId();
```

also I have tried with

```
$id = $quoteItem->getItemId();
```

It is throwing following Fatal error:

```
Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\code\local\Custom\Module\Model\Observer.php</b> on line <b>1053</b><br />
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong,I have taken reference from many other links too but none of them is working.

Comment: first of all check echo $quoteItem; look here is you are getting result or not

Comment: result of var_dump($quoteItem); is : NULL

Comment: $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem() this is not working check your function

Comment: please let me know that what should I do to make this work, I have tried everything.

Comment: Do you have any idea to get this id?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, You will not get QuoteItems keys for this event. This event provide items array which contain all the items which are getting added for a product. So you don't have to change your code a lot.

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getItems()[0];
$item_id =  $item->getId();
```

It should give you desired result.

Comment: this is returning empty result

Answer (score 1):

You should have an observer defined in your module config file which calls a method when someone adds an item to the basket. Something like the following;

```
    <events>
        <sales_quote_item_set_product>
            <observers>
                <quoteitem_set_eta_data>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>NameSpace_Eta_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>setEtaOnQuoteItem</method>
                </quoteitem_set_eta_data>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_item_set_product>
    </events>
```

Your observer method will then have access to the quote item using the following;

```
public function setEtaOnQuoteItem($oObserver) {
    $oQuoteItem = $oObserver->getQuoteItem();
    $quoteId = $oQuoteItem->getItemId();
}
```

Comment: this is not returning correct quote item id, this is returning first value of quote item id when there are multiple items in cart.

Comment: Sorry, didn't test the item id bit. This method is returning the Quote Item object. Try calling getItemId() on the item object instead. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Following code may help you,

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)
    ->loadByCustomer($customer);
$collection = $quote->getItemsCollection();
print_r($collection->getData());
```

Load customer with customer_id and get quote info, so you can get quote details.